# Splitting DATETIME up

Tags: php, html, datetime

I am wanting to split DATETIME up, so that I can put an "at" string in between, so that it would read:

Aug, 10, 2015 at 2:05pm

```
function fixDate($strDateTime) {

    $strFormat = 'm-d-Y';
    $intTimeStamp = strtotime($strDateTime);
    $strDate = date($strFormat, $intTimeStamp);
    $strTime = date('H:i', $intTimeStamp);

    if($strDate == date($strFormat)) {
        return "Today " . $strTime;
    }
    elseif($strDate == date($strFormat, strtotime('yesterday'))) {
        return "Yesterday " . $strTime;
    }
    else {
        return $strDate . " " . $strTime;
    }
}

$date = $row['topic_date'];
$date = fixDate($date);
```

HTML Part

```
<span>on<?php echo ' '.$date; ?></span>
```

I can't figure out how to put "at" in between the date and time and then for the date to read in string months rather than integers and for the time to not be in military time.

How can I do this?

Comment: `echo date('M, j, Y \a\t g:ia', $intTimeStamp)`?

Comment: Yes, like that. How can I make that work in my own code though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your function to run like this, using @MarcB's comment:

```
function fixDate($strDateTime) {

    $strFormat = 'M, j, Y';
    $strFormatTime = '\a\t g:ia';
    $intTimeStamp = strtotime($strDateTime);
    $strDate = date($strFormat, $intTimeStamp);
    $strTime = date($strFormatTime, $intTimeStamp);

    if($strDate == date($strFormat)) {
        return "Today " . $strTime;
    }
    elseif($strDate == date($strFormat, strtotime('yesterday'))) {
        return "Yesterday " . $strTime;
    }
    else {
        return $strDate . " " . $strTime;
    }
}

$date = $row['topic_date'];
$date = fixDate($date);
```

Comment: Perfect. This isn't part of my initial question, but it goes right along with it. You can see this part from my question `<span>on<?php echo ' '.$date; ?></span>`. If someone makes a post today, it ready "on Today at xxxxxxxxx". Is there a way I can change this, so thati f the date reads Today or Yesterday the "on" goes away?

Comment: move the `on` part into the function so that it prepends the `return $strDate . " " . $strTime;` like so `return "on " . $strDate . " " . $strTime;` then just remove it from the html

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help!!